# The temple or only temple

Tags: articles

Usually the article **the** is omitted before nouns when we refer to an object with its general meaning.

Example bedroom, home, temple, school

But when we talk about any specific object it cannot be omitted.

I think the following two examples are correct but their meaning is different

> I went to **the temple** with my parents, my aunts and my cousins.
>
> I went to **temple** with my parents, my aunts and my cousins.

But in the first sentence we are talking about a specific temple and in the second one any temple in general.

Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

> I went to the temple with my parents, my aunts and my cousins.

This would only imply that you physically visited a building (temple).

> I went to temple with my parents, my aunts and my cousins.

This would imply that you visited a temple and were engaged in regular worship services.

---

There are other examples for this:

> He went to school.

This means that he went to school to study and learn new things.

> He went to the school.

This means that he physically visited the premises for other purposes.